# Read command from file C#

Tags: c#

I want to try to read a command from a file, I just couldn't find the solution. What I'm doing is splitting the string like this

```
public string[] Stackoverflow()
{ 
    string raw = File.ReadAllText("something.txt") 
    return raw.Split(',')  
}
```

I couldn't find out how to split the split text.

Here's what I expect
Input:

```
say|hi , announce|hello , shout|stackoverflow
```

More than one command that responds to it.

Output:

hi

hello

stackoverflow

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried? The code you posted only attempts to resolve a small part of the question you're asking to have answered.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with this:

```cs
public IEnumerable<string[]> ReadFile(string fileName)
{ 
    var file = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
    var lines = file.Split(',');
    return lines.Select(line => line.Trim().Split('|'));
}
```

You can use it like this to get the output you want:

```
foreach(var item in ReadFile("something.txt"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item[1]);
}
```

You can see it work here (adjusted to skip the file input, which is not supported by .Net Fiddle):

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/wpN9tq

---

For fun, we can make the commands actually do something:

```
var commands = new Dictionary<string, Action<string>> {
    {"say", Console.WriteLine},
    {"announce", Console.WriteLine},
    {"shout", s => Console.WriteLine(s.ToUpper())}
};

var items = ReadFile("something.txt");
foreach(var item in items)
{
    if (commands.ContainsKey(item[0]))
    {
        commands[item[0]](item[1]);
    }
    else 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item[1]);
    }
}
```

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/A5PqBo

Comment: @Austin Definitely a good idea, but that's a job for the OP. Until they ask for it, I'd be totally guessing what the expectations are in that area.

Comment: @Austin It can have some downsides (there's still an allocation for the state machine, which isn't always as efficient as we'd like), but it almost always beats creating and returning a list.

Comment: Hmm... for this case, though, the foreach/yield could be a Select() instead.